# Corollary of definition of accumulation point

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm working with this definition of an accumulation point:

**Definition:** Let $A$ be a non-empty set of $\mathbb{R}$. We say $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is an accumulation point of $A$ is for every $\delta > 0$ we have that $$ (x - \delta, x + \delta) \cap (A \setminus \left\{x\right\} ) \neq \emptyset. $$

Then I need to prove that $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is an accumulation point of $A$ if for all $\delta > 0$ the set $$ (x- \delta, x + \delta) \cap A$$ contains infinitely many points.

**Attempt:** Let $A$ be a non-empty set of $\mathbb{R}$, and let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose $x$ is an accumulation point of $A$. Then, by definition, we have $$ \forall \delta > 0: (x - \delta, x + \delta) \cap (A \setminus \left\{x\right\} ) \neq \emptyset. $$ Now, suppose that $$ (x- \delta, x+ \delta) \cap A$$ contains a finite amount of points, say $\left\{y_1, \ldots, y_n \right\}$. Then for every $\delta_i$ we have that $$ x - \delta_i < y_i < x + \delta_i. $$ Now I want to derive a contradiction somehow, by using the fact that for every $\delta > 0$ the intersection $(x - \delta, x + \delta) \cap (A \setminus \left\{x\right\} )$ is non-empty. But I'm not sure how.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You would like to prove that $x$ is an accumulation point, given the above property with the $\delta.$ A proof by contradiction would start with something like "suppose $x$ is NOT an accumulation point and...contradiction". Besides, since you want to prove that $x$ IS an accumulation point how would you get a cotradiction the way you start your "proof"?

Comment: You only need to prove that the intersection is not void. For that you will need the definition about what means the "(" or ")" symbol in an interval.

Comment: False, because he's trying to prove the left to right implication, then the fact that x is an accumulation point is an hypotesis.

Answer (score 1):

Take $0 < \delta' < \min(|y_i - x|: i = 1,\ldots,n )$, then $(x-\delta', x+\delta')$ must also intersect $A \setminus \{x\}$ and this point is not one of the $y_i$, as it's closer to $x$ than any one them. Contradiction (we assumed we had a complete finite list but we have a new one).

Answer (score 1):

The contradiction comes the following way: consider the set $D:=\{d(x,y_i),i=1,...,n  \}$. Being the $y_i$ in a finite number $D$ has minimum $m$ different from $0$ because $y_i \neq x$ for every $i$. Just take $0 \neq\delta <m$: the set $A \cap[x-\delta,x+\delta]$ is empty because no $y_i$ is in it, yielding to a contradiction ($x$ wouldn't be an accumulation point.

For the other implication: since for every $\delta >0$ the set $A \cap[x-\delta,x+\delta]$ has infinitely many points then it also contains a point different from $x$, then $x$ is of accumulation by definition.

EDIT I read "x of accumulation iff every set....". Sorry fot the second part, that still is true and makes this property easier to remember.